# Boostrap 5 : Dropdown doesn't work in Bootstrap after installing it in NuxtJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nuxt.js

I have installed Bootstrap 5 in a Nuxt app
and I have added the Scss and the script file in the nuxt.config.js but when I try to add a dropdown to an element, it doesn't work the same as the hamburger menu I downloaded the JS from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/) and added it to my assets folder before importing to the nuxt.config file.

```
// scss
css:[
 { src: '~/assets/scss/app.scss', lang: 'scss' },
],


   // js
    script: [
        { src: '@/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' },
      ],
```

Comment: Make sure that you BoostrapJS PATH is Correct or I prefer CDN :)

Comment: yes sir i linked to the correct path

Comment: So I prefer CDN than offline library :)